# PhpStorm | WebMatrix (IISExpress) | Xdebug.remote_port | -- Which Port(s) to put where?

Tags: php, xdebug, iis-express, phpstorm, webmatrix-2

I've got a localhost webserver setup with WebMatrix and its IISExpress. It runs the webserver as `http://localhost:<port>`.
I've also installed xdebug in it which runs perfectly for error-handling purposes.

Now I have installed PhpStorm and I want to make use of its debugger's break-point wizardry. It uses Xdebug's `/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=<IDEKEY>` feature and This is where I'm having trouble.

In all, I have 3 places where I can set PORT:

- (a) Port in `xdebug.remote_port` in `php.ini`.
- (b) Port in WebMatrix.
- (c) Port in PhpStorm's `Server settings`, in `Run/Debug configuration`

> > > **EDIT**: There's an error here:
> > >       [image: (a)]
> > >       All those extra `"`quotes`"` and `;`colons`;`.

[image: (b)]

---

So far messing around, I've come to the conclusion that all three cannot be the same. otherwise it gives errors...

### [image: (a)][image: (b)]

---

Which port to use where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xdebug.remote_port` is used for the debugger connection, it must be different from the HTTP web port that you are using to access the page in a browser.

**xdebug.remote_port** needs to be the same as specified here:

[image: remote_port]

**HTTP port** (80 is the default for most servers, but when testing it could be 8080 or whatever you have configured in your web server settings) is configured here:

[image: HTTP port]

You may find it easier to use [Zero Debug Configuration](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) instead of using PHP Application Run/Debug configuration.