# Xdebug - command is not available

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I'm debugging remotely my project in PhpStorm. IDE shows 'Connected' for a moment and immediately goes into 'Waiting for incoming connection...'

Below is Xdebug log from this session

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: X.x.x.x:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
&gt; &lt;init xmlns=&quot;urn:debugger_protocol_v1&quot; xmlns:xdebug=&quot;http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot; fileuri=&quot;file:///xxx/info.php&quot; language=&quot;PHP&quot; protocol_version=&quot;1.0&quot; appid=&quot;4365&quot; idekey=&quot;10594&quot;&gt;&lt;engine version=&quot;2.2.2&quot;&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Xdebug]]&gt;&lt;/engine&gt;&lt;author&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]&gt;&lt;/author&gt;&lt;url&gt;&lt;![CDATAhttp://xdebug.org]&gt;&lt;/url&gt;&lt;copyright&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]&gt;&lt;/copyright&gt;&lt;/init&gt;

&lt;- feature_set -i 0 -n show_hidden -v 1
&gt; &lt;response xmlns=&quot;urn:debugger_protocol_v1&quot; xmlns:xdebug=&quot;http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot; command=&quot;feature_set&quot; transaction_id=&quot;0&quot; feature=&quot;show_hidden&quot; success=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;/response&gt;

&lt;- feature_set -i 1 -n max_depth -v 1
&gt; &lt;response xmlns=&quot;urn:debugger_protocol_v1&quot; xmlns:xdebug=&quot;http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot; command=&quot;feature_set&quot; transaction_id=&quot;1&quot; feature=&quot;max_depth&quot; success=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;/response&gt;

&lt;- feature_set -i 2 -n max_children -v 100
&gt; &lt;response xmlns=&quot;urn:debugger_protocol_v1&quot; xmlns:xdebug=&quot;http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot; command=&quot;feature_set&quot; transaction_id=&quot;2&quot; feature=&quot;max_children&quot; success=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;/response&gt;

&lt;- status -i 3
&gt; &lt;response xmlns=&quot;urn:debugger_protocol_v1&quot; xmlns:xdebug=&quot;http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot; command=&quot;status&quot; transaction_id=&quot;3&quot; status=&quot;starting&quot; reason=&quot;ok&quot;&gt;&lt;/response&gt;

&lt;- step_into -i 4
&gt; &lt;response xmlns=&quot;urn:debugger_protocol_v1&quot; xmlns:xdebug=&quot;http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot; command=&quot;step_into&quot; transaction_id=&quot;4&quot; status=&quot;stopping&quot; reason=&quot;ok&quot;&gt;&lt;/response&gt;

&lt;- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file://xxx/info.php -n 3
&gt; &lt;response xmlns=&quot;urn:debugger_protocol_v1&quot; xmlns:xdebug=&quot;http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug&quot; command=&quot;breakpoint_set&quot; transaction_id=&quot;5&quot;&gt;&lt;error code=&quot;5&quot;&gt;&lt;message&gt;&lt;![CDATA[command is not available]]&gt;&lt;/message&gt;&lt;/error&gt;&lt;/response&gt;
&quot;
```

According to Xdebug documentation status "stopping" is
'State after completion of code execution. This typically happens at the end of code execution, allowing the IDE to further interact with the debugger engine (for example, to collect performance data, or use other extended commands).'

So my debugger stops before reaching first breakpoint (set on first line).

Could it be a question of server configuration?

Comment: **1)** Does debugging works only in some files .. or it does not work at all (in this project) ? **2)** Is this remote project (xdebug and IDE are on different/virtual machines) ? **3)** Are symbolic paths in use? Right now it could be because of misconfigured path mapping ( A) xdebug works with de-linked/resolved/real paths while IDE may work with symlinked ones and B) local path differs from remote); **4)** xdebug is simply unable to break on certain breakpoints (e.g multi-line definition, loop body with no braces around etc) -- try setting it on basic simple line;

Comment: **5)** See if putting `xdebug_break();` will do any different (force breakpoint this way). Other than that -- see what happens from IDE side -- follow these instructions to collect more detailed php debug log: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: 1) Debugging doesn’t work at all for this server. 2) It’s on different machine, I’m behind NAT. 3) Yes, symbolic path are used. I think I added the correct path mapping in PhpStorm (the same way I did before in the past). 4) My script has 4 lines 
<?php
xdebug_break();
$a = 0;
echo $a;
5) xdebug_break(); changes nothing. Tomorrow I will follow DOC-1202 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

You should go to php.ini and delete a line like this

```
extension=php_xdebug-...
```

---

How did this line was created.

You put a xdebug's file into PHP extensions path like this

```
.../php5.X.XX/ext/
```

Now you may turn on this PHP extension by any _AMP UI tools like WAMP, XAMPP etc.

---

To prevent this painful misfortune you must put the Xdebug file into

```
.../php5.X.XX/zend_ext/
```

It'll make Xdebug hidden from any _AMP tool.

And correct your zend_extension parameter too.

```
zend_extension = .../php5.X.XX/ext/php_xdebug-...
```

to

```
zend_extension = .../php5.X.XX/zend_ext/php_xdebug-...
```

It's common default path for it.

---

Please, remember!
With PHPStorm, Eclipse, Zend etc., possibly you should consider to correct two php.ini files.

The first one for your web server. Commonly under Apache folder

```
...\Apache2.X.XX\bin\
```

The second one is for the direct PHP-script debugging. It lies in the PHP hosting folder:

```
...\php\php5.X.XX\
```

Comment: I missed this answer first time round because it was a little long winded, make sure xdebug.so module is being loaded correctly for your version of PHP. Rule of thumb; PHP >= 5.3 use `zend_extension=/path/to/xdebug.so` and thread PHP < 5.3 `zend_extension_ts=/path/to/xdebug`. There is more detail under heading **Configure PHP to Use Xdebug** here http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Comment: You solved my problem. Although another question matched mine exactly, so I answered it here with your help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35125321/631764

Comment: After hours of struggle, deleting the "extension=xdebug..." line worked, thank you

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the cause of the "`breakpoint_set`" / "`command is not available`" problem was disabled [`xdebug.extended_info`](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#extended_info) option (it is enabled by default but I disabled it for profiling).
Breakpoints do not work then `xdebug.extended_info` is disabled.
I have got breakpoints worked after reenabling `xdebug.extended_info`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem under windows, with phpstorm, i was googling many time. Eventually, my decision is the:

in `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.remote_mode = "jit"
```

From phpstorm tutorial, JIT - "Just-In-Time" Mode

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-xdebug.html#d43035e303

### UPD

No, this option does not helped me actually. But, i resolve my issue in the end:

I use phpstrom for win 7, and i configured the **path mapping** this way:

`d:\serverroot\vhost\www` => `d:\serverroot\vhost\www`

but in my old config i spied such mapping:

`d:\serverroot\vhost\www` => `d:/serverroot/vhost/www`

#### Finally

On windows machines in path mapping in server configuration replace the **`\`** by **`/`**

Comment: Generally speaking, check the php.ini configurations, both in cli and apache. I've added many things on php.ini and my issue was solved by copying the minimal php.ini configurations in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini taken from an official tutorial for my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only reason why this could happen is that your info.php has a syntax error. In that case, there is no code to execute and the script goes directly to "stopping" upon issue of the "step_into".

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Opcache / OPCache can cause this issue as well, if you have it enabled try disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be emitted when the XDebug extension is compiled into a non-debug build of the PHP runtime. The process will not fail (as it shouldn't), but the XDebug extension will stop doing anything for the duration of that process