# XAMPP PhpStorm XDebug not stopping on breakpoints

Tags: xampp, xdebug, phpstorm

I have a Windows 7 machine with XAMPP(Apache 2.4.4 - Win32 PHP 5.4.16) and PHPStorm 6.0.3 For the life of me I cannot get XDebug working on this machine!! I look at my PHPInfo page:
[image]

This tells me that I need to download XDebug "PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (64 bit)" I download and copy to produce: `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll` My PHP.ini has:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

I re-start XAMPP but the PHPInfo page still does not have XDebug in it?

Comment: `xdebug.remote_enable = 1`

Comment: **1)** You definitely have WRONG xdebug build. Why do you use **64-bit** xdebug while your PHP is 32-bit (your Apache seems to be 32-bit as well (Win32)). **2)** xdebug is turned off / disabled (`xdebug.remote_enable` should be **1/true/on**

Comment: Ok, how do i determine if my php is 32 bit? I saw the remote_enable and changed it to 1 I am running Window 7 and it says that it is the 64 bit version. How do I determine if the Apache is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Ok, I did PHP_INT_SIZE and it was 4 (32 bit) so I downloaded php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll (32 bit), changed my .ini to: zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll" but still the phpinfo.php page does not have anything for XDebug

Comment: From http://xdebug.org/docs/install : *"From **PHP 5.3 onwards**, you always need to use the **zend_extension** PHP.ini setting name, and not zend_extension_ts ..."*

Comment: ALSO: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide

Comment: *"how do i determine if my php is 32 bit?*" It's already shown in your phpinfo() output: **Architecture: x86** (64-bit will have different signature)

Comment: I also got this trouble.  
Consider to look at my answer here "[Xdebug - command is not available](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28309091/390940)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question is not what I wanted to do but here we go. I figured out that I was using XAMPP in 32bit mode - I added echo PHP_INT_SIZE; to the top of my phpinfo.php page and it returned 4 (32 bit) I downloaded "PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (32 bit)" but made my PHP.ini read:

zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll" - removing the _ts from zend_extension_ts

Answer (score 0):

In Additional:
Check security options of **.dll** xdebug file. If you see on file's icon small lock icon - nobody except you can't use this file. In that case add Users group in security tab in file's properties.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you should try to go to the php.ini and delete a line like this

```
extension=php_xdebug-...
```

It wasn't a good reason to put the Xdebug file here

```
C:\xampp\php\ext\
```

The better path is

```
C:\xampp\php\zend_extension\
```

More details are here "[Xdebug - command is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441719/xdebug-command-is-not-available/28309091#28309091)"

Answer (score 0):

*(This is for Mac, but written to work with Windows mostly)*

The confusion may come from which PHP your server is using. For example, there's the Mac OS X one, maybe one from "brew install...", and XAMPP's one.

1. Identify which PHP on your machine that PhpStorm is using. It's this one that needs XDebug. Let's use XAMPP's PHP. To find it,

   ```
   <?php phpinfo();?>
   ```

   Where it says `_SERVER["_"]` (on my Mac it's `_SERVER["_"] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php` ).
2. Does it have XDebug? (Search for 'xdebug' from the above `phpinfo();` output.) Mine does.

   [image: Search for xdebug in the phpinfo output]
3. If you don't, let's install it! Copy/paste entire text of phpinfo() output into this nifty [XDebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). Before I had XDebug, mine showed exact instructions:

   [image]

   - But also add this line `xdebug.remote_enable = 1` right below Step 8's so that XDebug will always be listening once told to do so!

   [image]
4. Restart XAMPP.
5. Download [XDebug Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en)
6. Go to the page you want to debug and select 'Debug' from the extension icon.
7. Go to PhpStorm preferences like this and select the correct "PHP Language Level", then click the 3 dots next to "CLI INTERPRETER" and put XAMPP's PHP path in the "PHP executable" field. It should say the Xdebug version on the right.

   [image: menus: phpstorm, then preferences, then Languages and Frameworks then PHP]
8. Go to PhpStorm preferences like this and add your paths; for me they're the same because mine's local, but it still needs to know "this page I'm hitting is this file on your machine". Click "OK".

   [image: menus: phpstorm, then preferences, then Languages and Frameworks, then servers]
9. Click the phone in top right and reload the page in your browser

   [image: button says Start listening for php debug connections]

Reload the page and it should stop at your first breakpoint it hits.