# XAMPP, Xdebug and phpStorm

Tags: xampp, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm having a heck of a time getting xdebug working on xampp. I'm trying to be able to debug php in the browser with phpStorm.

I'm on Windows 7 (64bit edition).

I downloaded the appropriate version of Xdebug (I think). PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (64 bit)

Put this in php.ini (the same php.ini from my phpinfo())

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts = "\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0RC1-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=”dbgp”
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
```

I had previous edited php.ini to change the default htdocs to another location (I am not sure if this would affect xdebug)

Also, I see the answer to many this kind of questions is to use the xdebug wizard. That's not working for me - doesn't tell me which binary to download for some reason.

Comment: deja vu?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491768/xampp-phpstorm-xdebug-not-stopping-on-breakpoints

Comment: Oh man, I was really hoping that was it. Changed my php.ini to this:
`[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\tmp"`
But still no joy

Comment: echo PHP_INT_SIZE; //=> 4
So that's useful to know, thanks!

Comment: Please read all comments, especially very first two. `xdebug.remote_enable = 1` (must be 1/on and not 0/off). And do not forget to restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LazyOne

Made sure I had the 32-bit version ([per this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491768/xampp-phpstorm-xdebug-not-stopping-on-breakpoints)).

Made sure xdebug.remote_enable = 1

The following is working:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\tmp"
```