# PhpStorm is not receiving xdebug connections : PhpStorm event log : Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I configured everything for PhpStorm and xdebug to work, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

the connection back to the IDE is not established, and I get this in the IDE event Log

**Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])' –  Osama Salama 13 mins ago**

I'll put together configuration values I configured in various places. As I can't find out where is the problem

php.ini

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_log=xxx/xdebug.log
xdebug.IDE_key=PHPSTORM
```

PHP info

xdebug

```
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.3.1
IDE Key PHPSTORM

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value

xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart On  On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log   /home/nautilus/Desktop/xdebug.log   /home/nautilus/Desktop/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

**I also validated the remote debugging env. it's all good.** https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/validating-the-configuration-of-a-debugging-engine.html which also came out fine.

**The last possible resort is the xdebug log file:**

```
Log opened at 2015-03-13 14:39:01
I: Checking remote connect back address.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000. :-|
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="dbgp://stdin" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="4474"><engine version="2.3.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2015 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>
<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>
<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>
<- status -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>
<- step_into -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="5" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
<- eval -i 6 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="6"><error code="5"><message><![CDATA[command is not available]]></message></error></response>
Log closed at 2015-03-13 14:39:01
```

Comment: Accordingly to the log it's receiving them -- connection is established, communication is done. I just do not see any info about what file it's working with and no info about any breakpoints.

Comment: I see that you have added more info: Is it a CLI script you are trying to debug or is it via browser? If browser -- what web server do you have there?

Comment: via browser, on chrome

Comment: And what **web server** do you have there? Nginx?

Comment: Apache 2. I have tried everything to make this work.

Comment: Any way to see your Apache config for this site? So far it looks like Apache misconfiguration: IDE expects server name variable to be present .. but it's empty. What `$_SERVER['SERVE_NAME']` says (from `phpinfo()`output obtained via web browser)?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work yesterday but it seems odd, the reason why the IDE is not fetching the frames, is because my browser runs the script at localhost:63342 where it's actually running on localhost, once i remove the port number on the browsers frames are fetched and everything is fine stepping through. for some reason the IDE runs the script at this port number, despite the warning issued by the IDE.

Comment: The `localhost:63342` URL means that **built-in simple web server** is used. To use your own server, you have to create and  configure **deployment entry** and mark it as Default.

Comment: I had the same problem caused by both PHP extensions "Xdebug" and "Zend Debugger" being active at the same time. Disabling "Zend Debugger" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the exact same error in PhpStorm as the OP.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28309091/631764) to a different question solved the problem for me, but I would like to add more detail in my own answer.

The main issue was improperly loaded xdebug. The server mapping issues mentioned in other answers was not an issue for me.

If you load your `phpinfo()` page and find the xdebug section, and you see this:

[image: XDEBUG NOT LOADED AS ZEND EXTENSION]

> XDEBUG NOT LOADED AS ZEND EXTENSION

Then you have to fix that before you try anything else! But sometimes this can take some work to track down, if you have multiple `php.ini` files.

Also in your `phpinfo()` page, search for "php.ini", (it should be right near the top) and see your "Configuration File (php.ini) Path", and your "Loaded Configuration File". Those are where your xdebug may be loading.

[image]

In my case, I correctly loaded it as a Zend extension in my main configuration file in /usr/local/lib/php.ini, like so:

```
zend_extension = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
```

But in my Loaded Configuration file in /home/someuser/public_html/php.ini, I had it incorrectly loaded like this:

```
extension=xdebug.so
```

After fixing that, remote debugging with PhpStorm is working again for me.

As a side note, the first error I saw in PhpStorm was the exact same one the OP mentions, and here is what it looks like:

[image: PhpStorm xdebug server variables error]

```
Cannot accept external Xdebug connection
Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'
```

( At first I thought that, because the extension was not loaded properly, PhpStorm was not able to execute PHP code on the server. But now I think PhpStorm only executes php code if you configured an interpreter, which isn't necessary for debugging. For debugging, PhpStorm just needs the xdebug connection and the correct path mappings.)

Later, I found the "Command is not available" error in the xdebug log on my server, which led me to the solution.

Here, by the way, is what I have in my local `php.ini` for xdebug:

```
;extension=xdebug.so <- this is the bad line commented!
zend_extension = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug-someuser/"
xdebug.profile_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log="var/log/xdebug/xlog"
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I had configure as zend extension but this issue still happen

Answer (score 9):

I have recently had the same problem attempting to debug using `PHPStorm` under `nginx` and `php-fpm`, in my case this was not related to the `xdebug`, `nginx` or `php-fpm config`, it was the path mappings in `phpstorm` that were missing.

Initially `PHPStorm` will notify you when it cannot map a file on the server to a local source file however if it has a mapping to the first files hit ( normally `index.php` or some such ) but it cannot map a file used at a later stage ( in my case this was the autoloader in the vendor directory of a project using composer ) then `PHPStorm` will not be able to debug any further and debugging will stop.

In order to rectify this in `PHPStorm` go to `settings/Languages & Frameworks/PHP/Servers` and ensure the root of your project is mapped correctly to it's counterpart directory on the server.

`PHPStorm` should then be able to map all the files in your project and debugging should continue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, This is all true, and became my standard practice when working with new php projects, Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Also same error if you missed to set environment variable in `docker-compose.yml` for your workspace configuration:

`workspace:
        build:
          environment:
            - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}`

Comment: Where is the bash variable supposed to come from?

Comment: @Shardj from the hosts environment (when you call `docker` or `docker-compose`) or a `.env` file.

Comment: I think I meant where's the value for ${PHP_IDE_CONFIG} supposed to come from however it's been two years so I can't be sure. Currently I have PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=docker" set within my docker container to allow for cli debugging

Comment: @DanielW. docker-compose can use the values from an .env file or you export the variable before you call docker-compose up

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming to this issue, there is another potential configuration option that you could be missing.

Make sure that you have correctly configured your server to use the correct path mapping between your local and remote files.

For example, if your site root is mounted locally at `/home/foo/www/mysite` but installed on the server at `/www/mysite` then you will need to edit your server configuration in PHPStorm to use path mappings (simply enter `/www/mysite` in the box alongside `/home/foo/www/mysite`).

Comment: It's making me do this for every single file individually, it won't let me just set mapping for the top level folder.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hey - just set it at the root folder and all other files should be relative to that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well and tried every trick I could find, but nothing worked. For me, debugging works most of the time, but sometimes it just stops working with the message:
"Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'"

So I eventually realized I had a compilation error in my code (misspelled method name - PhpStorm does not always report these things, at least in my setup). As soon as I corrected the error debugging started working again. Maybe this can help someone struggling.

Although I still have issues with breakpoints not being hit, I can throw in a "xdebug_break();" line in the code and debugging becomes more reliable. The downside with using xdebug_break instead of breakpoints is (apart from the fact that it's more work than just adding a breakpoint) the local variables not being displayed in the PhpStorm debugger for some reason (only globals are shown). That makes debugging less convenient, but at least I can make it work.

Apparently you can't have everything :)
Coming from the Java world, good debugging is just something I have been able to take for granted, but I have now realized how spoiled I have been :)

Comment: i can relate...i was spoilt from the c# world too ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is to make sure that you disable any firewall you have and which 
might block remote connections.

Comment: For this, I would suggest using ssh tunneling. That way you keep your firewall in place and still can do the remote debugging. It will work even if you don't have access to the firewall/router settings. It was a bit tricky to set up though. You have to pay careful attention to the tutorials.