# PhpStorm: Cannot evaluate expression '$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']'

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using a Docker container running PHP 7.1 (php-fpm) and Nginx. I have installed and enabled Xdebug 2.5.0 (as image below shown).

[image]

I am trying to debug a single `index.php` file with this lines of code using "Zero Debug Configuration":

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression
>   '$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']'

I have search for similar issues and I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035705/phpstorm-is-not-receiving-xdebug-connections-phpstorm-event-log-cannot-evalu) but nothing there helped me so far.

Here is the PhpStorm configuration related to Debug:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am not sure what is failing here so I need some help around this. The repository with the Dockerfile and so on is [here](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker). I am using the following version of PhpStorm:

```
PhpStorm 2016.3.2 EAP
Build #PS-163.10154.2, built on December 13, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b2 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Can any give me some help? What I am missing on this setup?

Comment: *"$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']"* that's a new one -- have not seen port issue before. It's quite possible that your nginx configuration is incomplete (not properly configured). Please check what `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` shows in your `phpinfo()` output (capture it via browser). **P.S.** Do not touch DBGp Proxy settings if you do not use them.

Comment: I'm not a nginx expert (never used it) .. but this line *potentially* is what causing the issue: https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/container-files/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params#L25 (EDIT: actually -- not this line .. but the idea is similar -- see next sentence). In any case --  `SERVER_PORT` variable should be present in `$_SERVER` and port number should match the one you are using.

Comment: @LazyOne I am having another issue and I am not sure what I messed up. At the `Dockerfile` I am exposing the port `9001` then on the `docker-compose.yml` I am mapping the port from the container to the host as follow: `9002:9001` then as soon as I try to start a debug session in phpStorm I end up with this error: `Can't start listening for connections from 'xdebug': Port 9002 is busy`, why? What I miss here?

Comment: Not a Docker user .. but from all the manuals I have read -- you should not expose such ports -- that port IDE will use to listen locally -- **it's xdebug that will be connecting to IDE and not other way around**. By making it exposed in Docker (so you can connect from Host machine into a container) .. you preventing IDE from listening that port.

Comment: @LazyOne you're right I just found this commented out `fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT       $server_port;` and that was causing the issue, it's working now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using unix: socket instead of TCP protocol.
Reconfigure PHP-FPM and NGINX to use TCP