# PhpStorm - Cannot accept external Xdebug connection

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, codeception

I am having an error running the tests for my application in PhpStorm using Codeception. My code is running through Vagrant.

In the top line of my **index.php** for the Codeception test is:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
```

I installed xdebug through homebrew and that's in my php version output:

```
PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2017 12:15:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

When I run the tests though I get an error in PhpStorm event log:

```
Cannot accept external Xdebug connection: Cannot evaluate expression 'isset($_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'])'
```

In my PhpStorm settings I have it set up to accept external connections:

[image]

and in php info I have xdebug setting available:

```
$ php -i | grep xdebug                 
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
...
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
```

In the **/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini** I set `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049776/xdebug-for-remote-server-not-connecting).

What can I do to remove the `Cannot accept external Xdebug connection` error and run tests?

Comment: Hmm, the `$_SERVER['PHP_IDE_CONFIG']` is intended for remote CLI debugging I think . Missing idekey? `xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"`. Read this already?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035705/phpstorm-is-not-receiving-xdebug-connections-phpstorm-event-log-cannot-evalu Mine works but I have to click little green phone button  to "listen",

Comment: setting the idekey did not fix or change the error. I do have the green telephone on listening for debug connections

Comment: So, with this approach, you are raising a flag in the request to tell the IDE to pick up. Look at the request, how is the variable passed in the request? Think I've used a browser toolbar button to add it in when I want to debug in IDE.

Comment: Here we go: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Browser+Debugging+Extensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the remote port to an unused one such as 9898:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_port = 9898
```

And then update that in PhpStorm settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, (using Symfony framework and PhpStorm )it was just related to some cache i had to clean! Took me 2 hours to figure out as I have everything configured and properly set but still the Events didn't fire up.

So please clear always the cash whenever you have a clueless issue like this: if it didn't work, then move on t other steps to debug the source of the issue.