# PhpStorm doesn't stop on breakpoints with PhpUnit?

Tags: phpstorm

When I run a test using PhpUnit from PhpStorm it doesn't stop on my breakpoints. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

If your debugger seems to be connected, then you need to confirm whether your breakpoints are disabled. Make sure that the checkpoint in front of breakpoint is enabled.
The link below has more information on ensuring path mapping is correct.

These might help:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Troubleshooting+PhpStorm+debugging#TroubleshootingPhpStormdebugging-Breakpointsarenotbeinghit

Similar question is answered here as well. You can check it out:

[PhpStorm debugger not stopping at BreakPoints; keeps waiting for xdebug _SESSION_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120513/phpstorm-debugger-not-stopping-at-breakpoints-keeps-waiting-for-xdebug-session)

Good Luck